# Why does retrieving the count of today's emails return zero?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have written code to check Outlook folders which contain mails that correspond to a certain date.

The date values are in cells `C3:C6` and are called by the do until loop. The mailboxes are in `B3:B6` and are called by the for next loop.

Somehow, the macro does not get the count of mails with the date of today, while there are several mails with the date of today in those inboxes.

```
Sub HowManyDatedEmails()

' Set Variables
Dim objOutlook As Object, objnSpace As Object, objFolder As Object
Dim EmailCount As Integer, DateCount As Integer, iCount As Integer
Dim myDate As Date
Dim arrEmailDates()

' Get Outlook Object
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objnSpace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

For b = 3 To Range("C:C").Count
    ' Get Folder Object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objFolder = objnSpace.Folders(Range("C" & b).Value).Folders("Inbox")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        MsgBox "No such folder."
        Set objFolder = Nothing
        Set objnSpace = Nothing
        Set objOutlook = Nothing
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Put ReceivedTimes in array
    EmailCount = objFolder.Items.Count
    For iCount = 1 To EmailCount
        With objFolder.Items(iCount)
            ReDim Preserve arrEmailDates(iCount - 1)
            arrEmailDates(iCount - 1) = DateSerial(Year(.ReceivedTime), Month(.ReceivedTime), Day(.ReceivedTime))
        End With
    Next iCount

    ' Clear Outlook objects
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objnSpace = Nothing
    Set objOutlook = Nothing

    ' Count the emails dates equal to active cell

    Range("D3").Select

    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)

        DateCount = 0
        myDate = ActiveCell.Value

        For i = 0 To UBound(arrEmailDates) - 1
            If arrEmailDates(i) = myDate Then DateCount = DateCount + 1
        Next i

        Selection.Offset(0, 1).Activate
        ActiveCell.Value = DateCount
        Selection.Offset(1, -1).Activate
    Loop
Next b
End Sub
```

Comment: I ran into a similar issue before, solved by +1 day on the receive date.

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code you can change the If condition based on your requirement, here in Column D today date will be pasted and code will extract the Email if received date is greater than the date in Column D.

Code:

```
Sub HowManyDatedEmails()
Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutlookNamespace As Namespace
Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
Dim Folder As MAPIFolder
Dim OutlookMail As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Mail")
Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
Set OutlookNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Folder = OutlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
i = 1
For Each OutlookMail In Folder.Items
    If OutlookMail.ReceivedTime > ws.Range("D" & i).Value And OutlookMail.Subject <> ws.Range("B" & i).Value Then
        ws.Range("B1").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.Subject
        ws.Range("C1").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.ReceivedTime
        ws.Range("D1").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.ReceivedTime
        ws.Range("E1").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.SenderName
        ws.Range("F1").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.Body
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next OutlookMail
Set Folder = Nothing
Set OutlookNamespace = Nothing
Set OutlookApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Thank You

Comment: Your code works, however it does not allow me to show from which mailbox each mail is taken.. Do you know how to add that?

Comment: _which mailbox means?_ what information you required from Email?

Comment: In outlook I have 6 different mailboxes. Example: one info@ mailbox, one jstns@ mailbox, one invoice@ mailbox. I would like to also know which mail came from which mailbox